# How to connect to socket io via ssl, serving files by apache2

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io

I've been trying to set up SSL on NodeJS, serving `index.html` through an Apache2 server using CertBot certificates.

Unfortunetly, when I try to make the client to connect to the Server via https, It throws the following error

```
[index.js:83 GET https://pxlloewe.de:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NJ9t2YZ net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR][1]
```

[image: console]

So, is it possible to still provide the files via appache2 and ssl and connect to the Server with the page loaded `https:youDomain.com`?

I tried to get https running on the NodeJS Server but I am don't want to provide the browser files via Express

Here is my code, if someone got the chance to read sth out of it:

Serverside:

```
var express = require("express");
var socket = require("socket.io");

var app = express();
const port = 3000
var server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Express App auf Port: ", port)
});

//Socket Setup
var io = socket(server);

io.on("connection", function(){
    console.log("Verbunden auf websocket")
})
```

Clientside:

```
<html>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-v8ng/uGxkge3d1IJuEo6dJP8JViyvms0cly9pnbfRxT6/31c3dRWxIiwGnMSWwZjHKOuY3EVmijs7k1jz/9bLA==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Einfache Chat App</title>
    <script src="chat.js"></script>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// Make Connection
var socket = io.connect('pxlloewe.de:3000', {secure: true});
```

Comment: You can setup a reverse proxy with apache2

Comment: This requires to serve to files via express, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: No it doesn't require you to serve file using express

Comment: But how to set this up then?

Comment: Do you use apache2 or ngix

Comment: apache2, never heared of ngix before

Comment: I mean nginx. Sorry it was typo.

Comment: Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I follow to get things working:

1. added a subdomain to my main domain (websocket.pxllloewe.de)
2. routing to my dyndns (got my Server running at home on a raspberryPi)
3. setting up apache2/LetsEncrypt via Certbot and Proxy. MyConfig:

   ServerName websocket.pxlloewe.de
            ServerAdmin Ich@bin.Gut
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/pxlloewe_de
            ProxyPreserveHost On
            ProxyRequests Off
            ProxyPass /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io
            ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io

   ```
        #ProxyPass /socket.io http://localhost/
        #ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost/

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/pxlloewe.de-0001/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/pxlloewe.de-0001/privkey.pem
   ```

Thanks for your help Aviv Lo! Working out fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I am grabbing this apache site conf. straight from my site in production. It is then modified to suite your need.

```sh
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName pxlloewe.de
        #ServerAlias www.pxlloewe.de
        ServerAdmin admin@pxlloewe.de
        DocumentRoot /var/www/pxlloewe_de

        LogLevel debug  ssl:info
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/pxlloewe.de.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/pxlloewe.de.key

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket              [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} upgrade             [NC]
        RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://127.0.0.1:3000/$1 [P,L]

        ProxyPass "/socket.io" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io"
        ProxyPassReverse "/socket.io" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io"


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/knct_error_https.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/knct_access_https.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: After fixing the Certificates file path, It now throws this at me:

`Invalid command 'ProxyPass', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

searched for a solution, but I didnt find one

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention but you have to enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_wstunnel.

Comment: Looks now like apache ist loading the config without any problems, but the client still can not connect to the socket with https. It still throws `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: Created a git to paste in my code:

https://github.com/PxlLoewe/socket.io/tree/master

Comment: Change  `var socket = io.connect('pxlloewe.de:3000', {secure: true});` to `var socket = io.connect('pxlloewe.de, {secure: true});`

Comment: now created another subdomain, wich looks like to work, but socket io still cant connect to it:https://github.com/PxlLoewe/socket.io/blob/master/000-default.conf
`var socket = io.connect("https://test.pxlloewe.de", {secure: true});`

Comment: How things should be is that you have your socket io server running on some port (3000) for example while the Apache2 is running on let's say 433 for SSL. Set a document root (something like /bar/www/pxlLoewe) in the apache2 conf and create the directory for it. Put the file that you want to serve in the document root so apache2 will just serve these files when the client connects using http/https protocol. While in the apache2 conf, the reverse proxy directive should redirect all the connection using 'websocket' (not http/https) to the actual port that the socket io server is running (3000)

Comment: Working now, see answer.